# Worksheet Change event not running on other computers

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where I wrote the below code to run whenever any of the defined cells change. The sheet works perfectly on the computer I created the sheet in but when I took it to a customer site using their computer it did not work.

Not sure what changes I have to make to make it work, I read a few articles that speak about the `application.enableevents` code and I tried placing it in a few spots but it didn't work, any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Target.Address = "$D$7" Then              'loan type
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$D$8" Then              'credit score
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$D$9" Then              'more than 1 borrower
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$C$12" Then             'income
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$D$21" Then
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$D$21" Then             'sales price
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$D$23" Then             'loan amount
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$H$4" Then              'taxes
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$H$5" Then              'insurance
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$H$6" Then              'HOA
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$H$7" Then              'term
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$H$8" Then              'rate
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$H$17" Then             'car payment
        Call Calc_MI
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$H$18" Then             'credit cards/loans
        Call Calc_MI
    End If

    If Range("H13").Value > Range("H11").Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingX").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingCheck").Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("H13").Value <= Range("H11").Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingX").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingCheck").Visible = True
    End If

    If Range("H14").Value > Range("H12").Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTIX").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTICheck").Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("H14").Value <= Range("H12").Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTIX").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTICheck").Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the Calc_MI code:

```
Sub Calc_MI()

    'ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Mortgage1"

    If Range("D7").Value = "FHA" Then
        Range("H9").Value = 0.85
    Else
        If Range("E24").Value < 0.8001 Or Range("D7").Value = "VA" Then
            Range("H9").Value = ""
        Else
            If Range("H14").Value > 0.45 Then
                Range("H9").Value = (Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("BM100").Value +
                Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("BM101").Value + Sheets("Closing
                Costs").Range("BM102").Value)
            Else
                Range("H9").Value = (Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("BM100").Value +
                Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("BM102").Value)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet what the problem is but if in case you were right about needing to use `Application.EnableEvents`, you have to set it to `False` at first, and then back to `True` when you're done with it

Comment: That didn't work, I set it to false at the beginning of the code then to true at the end. Why does it work perfectly on the computer i created it? Could it be a global excel setting?

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of your long chain of `If...Else` statements, you could use something like `If Not Intersect(Target, [D7:D9], [C12], [D21:D23], ...) Is Nothing`.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Is your code throwing an error somewhere? Is it executing but not giving the expected results? Have you tried a very simple, basic test? Are you both running the same version of Excel?

Comment: To add to @Freeman, assuming that the macro just isn't doing anything, have you confirmed that the security level of the second PC isn't automatically disabling macros?

Comment: What concerns me about your code is that you don't have any error handling.  If this code fails after the Application.EnableEvents = False, then events won't fire on that PC until that property is reset.  You should have an On Error GoTo error handler to make sure that if the code fails, the Application.EnableEvents gets reset to True.

Comment: @FrankBall good suggestion, added that to mine

Comment: @Marcucciboy2  Error handling is the one thing that I see most people writing VBA code seem to miss.  Even in this code, the fact that it relies on specifically named sheets (which can get deleted or renamed) and has nothing to handle that is a big problem.  Any time you are specifically referring to named ranges, sheets, etc. there should be checks to make sure that those ranges/sheets do actually exist.  We'd all love it if users only did what they are supposed to do, but given a little bit of information, they can end screwing up even the most basic workbooks.

Comment: @FrankBall I understand your sentiment but there are just too many people that come here not even knowing their sheet's current name, let alone the codename for that sheet. Imo with the way that SO is set up and the limited number of comments that they want you to make, it's not a great place for making code bulletproof

Comment: I just can't help but keep tying to educate people on this...  I've had to fix so many workbooks that ended in bad states because of a lack of error handling that I try to get people to learn this at every opportunity.  Any time I see Application,ScreenUpdating, Application.EnableEvents or the like and there's no error handling to make sure that in the event of failure, those setting get set back to where they should, I just cringe...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what @jsheeran means regarding simplifying your code so that it's a lot more readable and easy to adjust in the future.

However, I'll be honest that I'm not totally sure yet what's causing your **actual** problem which is not allowing this to run on other computers.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Goto ErrLabel
    Dim calcMi As Range
    Set calcMi = Range("D7:D9,C12,D21,D23,H4:H8,H17:H18")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Call Calc_MI
    End If


    If Range("H13").value > Range("H11").value Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingX").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingCheck").Visible = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingX").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("HousingCheck").Visible = False
    End If


    If Range("H14").value > Range("H12").value Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTIX").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTICheck").Visible = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTIX").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTICheck").Visible = False
    End If

ErrLabel:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub Calc_MI()

    'ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Mortgage1"

    If Range("D7").value = "FHA" Then
        Range("H9").value = 0.85
    Else
        If Range("E24").value < 0.8001 Or Range("D7").value = "VA" Then
            Range("H9").value = ""
        Else
            With sheets("Closing Costs")
                Range("H9").value = .Range("BM100").value + .Range("BM102").value

                If Range("H14").value > 0.45 Then
                    Range("H9").value = Range("H9").value + .Range("BM101").value
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If

    'ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: Marcucciboy2, your code does not trigger calc_mi routine when the fields are changed even on my computer.

Comment: I also did a whole project search for Application.EnableEvents and don't have that anywhere in the project.

Comment: I found the problem and it is completely unrelated to anything I would have ever thought. The problem had to do with the date picker addon I had on the computer I wrote the sheet in. The other computers do not have this and whenever I opened the sheet on any other computer it would be stuck in design mode where it cannot execute macros. I removed that pesky date picker and resent sheet and all is working back to normal. Sheesh I have had this issue for 3 days now.